# Mapping intr to del key

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, signals, putty

I am in the process of migrating a legacy 4GL application from SCO OpenServer 5.0.7 to CentOS (Red Hat) Linux 5.9.

There are a number of screens that prompt the user to press "DEL to ABORT" but is actually trapping the interrupt signal.

How can I map `stty intr` to the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key for consistency?  Is it possible to map interrupt to an ansi sequence?

PuTTY is generating the following control codes for each of these keys:

<kbd>DEL</kbd>: `^[[3~`

<kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>: `^?`

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>: `^H`

I can't find an option within PuTTY to remap the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key specifically.

Answer (score 7):

The `intr` character, has to be a character, it can't be a sequence of characters.

As Random832 suggested, using `screen` is probably your best bet. It would then work from any terminal.

`screen` emulates a terminal inside another terminal. By default, the terminal it emulates sends `^?` on <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and `^[[3~` on <kbd>Delete</kbd> just like PuTTY, but you can change that.

For instance, if you create a file that contains:

```
bindkey -k kb stuff "\10"
bindkey -k kD stuff "\177"
termcap * '' 'kD=\177:kb=\10'
screen sh -c 'stty intr "^?" erase "^H"; exec my-legacy-app'
```

And use it as `screen -c /path/to/that-file`

It would emulate one where <kbd>Backspace</kbd> sends `^H` and <kbd>Delete</kbd> sends `^?`.

The third line is to tell so to applications that use termcap (via the `$TERMCAP` environment variable), but note that those using `terminfo` would not get notified.

Answer (score 6):

The character it's expecting is ^?, which was a key labeled DEL on their legacy terminals (e.g. VT220).

You can do stty intr ^? before starting the application to make it use this for the interrupt signal, but I don't know if there's a way to configure Putty to send it for DEL. I know some other terminals allow it to be remapped.

You can't just change the message it prints?

You may need a different terminal emulator, or an extra terminal emulation layer similar to screen between your terminal and the application.

EDIT: If you select the "SCO" option under "Function keys and keypad", the DEL key should generate `^?`, which you can map to stty intr. You should also set Backspace to Control-H. It's also possible that the application may expect the character sequences the Home, End, etc keys generate in this mode, since you said it was an app designed to run on a SCO operating system.

However, you should consider @StephaneChazelas' answer, since using screen for this would create a more controlled environment (i.e. you wouldn't have to configure putty on everyone's client machine)

Comment: I have temporarily mapped interrupt to `^H` but the users insist on keeping the DEL key.

Comment: @JamesA See my edit.